# How to display diffrence divs according to radio selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 radio buttons no one of them checked by default and I want if any one of them checked a Div appear according to what radio button was checked.
( Divs have different content )

and if the selection changed the one which appeared now disappear and the other appear.

and when one of them appear there are another 2 radio to do the same thing for another one div ( one to show and one to hide )

Here what I tried to do

**JavaScript**

```
function haitham()
{   
    if(document.getElementById('s').checked == true)
    {
      document.getElementById('StudentData').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('GraduateData').style.display = "none";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('g').checked == true)
    {
      document.getElementById('GraduateData').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('StudentData').style.display = "none";
    }
}

function info()
{   
    if(document.getElementById('y').checked == true)
    {
      document.getElementById('MoreInfo').style.display = "block";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('n').checked == true)
    {
      document.getElementById('MoreInfo').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
            <input class="margin2" id="s" type="radio" name="kind" value="student" onchange="haitham()"
            required="required" />Student
            <input class="margin2" id="g" type="radio" name="kind" value="graduate" onchange="haitham()"
            required="required" />Graduate


<div id="StudentData">
     content 1
     <input class="margin2" id="y" type="radio" name="info" value="yes" onchange="info()"
            required="required" />Student
     <input class="margin2" id="n" type="radio" name="info" value="no" onchange="info()"
            required="required" />Graduate

</div>

<div id="GraduateData">
     content 2   

</div>

<div id="MoreInfo">
     content 3
</div>
```

the first work good but the other 2 radio did not work although it should be the same

Thank you ...

Comment: What HTML are you working with? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem wasn't a javascript or html one, it was actually a CSS issue. Your code was fine, aside from the fact that the `values for display are "none" and "block"` not "" and "hidden". I modified your code and updated the fiddle.

Here's the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/8JpSQ/4/

Comment: kindly, can you  it with JavaScript not JQuery

Comment: Not that i've included the JS in the head of the document (look on the left in jsfiddle)... including it elsewhere seemed to cause problems and probably would for you aswell.

Comment: Thank you very much CoryDanielson .. I felt that the problem was not in javascript :)

Comment: You can only use each ID one time. You have 2 HTML elements with `id="y"` and `id="n"`

Comment: even if I change id name it still not working, I have deleted the two radio button from the other div and the first still not working.

Comment: I'm taking a look. There are definitely a few problems with the code aside from the ID's.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8JpSQ/9/ Ok, now what do you want to happen when you click Radio 1 or Radio 2?

Comment: I have 4 divs, First one appear by default, at the end of it there are 2 radio buttons when check one of them the second or third div appears according to what radio buuton checked, what ever appear of them there are another 2 radio buttons at the end of it, one of them to appear the fourth div and the other to hide it.
here are the code without styling
http://jsfiddle.net/8JpSQ/8/

Comment: Thanks, would you mind marking my post as "best answer" again. Editing your original post unmarked it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a clicked event to the radio buttons, and through a Javascript function change the attribute of the respective DIV to hidden when required. To show it instead, remove the attribute 'hidden'. Also, we'd probably be able to help more if you can post some code showing what you tried/what went wrong. But what I suggested should be the general approach to make what you want happen.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your HTML is, so here's what I have:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  $('.divWrapper > div').eq($(this).index()).fadeOut().siblings().fadeIn();
});
```

I'm assuming this is your structure:

```
<form>
  <checkbox>
  <checkbox>
  ...
</form>

<div class="divWrapper">
  <div>
  <div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably mention that this involves the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com), which doesn't appear to be among the tags to the question (as yet, at least).

Comment: I'm just so used to thinking in jQuery selectors I don't realize it. My bad!

Comment: Yeah, I've been caught that way a few times, too...no worries! =)